# CascadeType.Persist not working with primary key generator type table in JPA

Tags: jpa

I have an issue using CascadeType.Persist for my JPA/Standalone project. I have a Parent entity which has a List of Child entities that should be persisted along with the Parent and the primary key of Parent is generated using the Table(GeneratorType.TABLE) and I use a table to generate the Primary Key.

In Parent I have :

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.DETACH})
    List<Child> children;
    //Getter and Setter

    @PostPersist
    public void setParentID(){
    System.out.println("Inside Postpersist");
    for(Child ch : this.children){
        ch.setParent(this);
                    System.out.println(ch.getParent().getParentId());
    }
}
```

In Child :

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Parent_ID")
    private Parent parent;
```

In the DB I have a not null set to Parent_ID column of the Parent table. When I persist a Parent entity and it has been set with list of Child entities it throws a

```
    ConstraintViolationException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Parent_ID', table 'jpaTest.Child', column does not allow nulls.
```

as the Parent is null for all the Child entities though it prints the ParentId set to every Child entity in the method annotated with @PostPersist

However this does not occur and persistence of parent and child takes place when I change the primary key generation strategy from TABLE type to AUTO. How and why is this happening.

The provider is Hibernate. And my DB server is the mssql.

Answer (score 2):

That approach looks little bit weak, because specification does not give too much support for modifying other entities in life cycle callbacks:

> In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not
>   invoke EntityManager or Query operations, access other entity
>   instances, or modify relationships within the same persistence
>   context.

Additionally, you do not have guarantee about order of cascade to *children* and *@PostPersist* in parent:

> It is implementation-dependent as to whether callback methods are
>   invoked before or after the cascading of the lifecycle events to
>   related entities. Applications should not depend on this ordering.

Comment: Hey thanks. In that case i cannot depend on the cascading effect for persisting the Children. Well it does the persisting but the ID of Parent in the Child table is set to null as the ID is generated while insert operation and not set before. Therefore I opted the event listeners callback approach to set the ParentId to the child entities before the cascading effects took place. Thanks anyways I ll persist the Child in the business code rather than postpersist of the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Yes It worked without omitting the cascade-persist. All i had to do was set the Parent object to the Child while adding Child entities to the list of children in Parent as it is a bidirectional relationship.

In the Parent:

```
    public void setParentToChild(Child ch){
    if(this.getChildren()==null){
        this.children = new ArrayList<Children>();
    }
            this.children.add(cb);
            //this is what worked. Also set the Parent to Child
    cb.setCustomer(this);
}
```

Now while creating new Parent and Child i call this method to add child to parent. And JPA does the rest nothing to set in the business code. Thanks to you guys.

Comment: I have the same problem you had(parentId in the Child table is null). I have now used `@PostPersist`, but everyone says it is not a good idea. Can you please explain to me how you have solved the problem? I seem to have no good ideas, and I am a bit desperate.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the child's parent field must be initialized *before* persisting the parent, and not after, in the @PostPersist method, which is probably called after the cascade has been done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply JB. Well by the result of the PostPersist event in the Parent entity class, it is clear that before persisting the child the ParentId is set for it. It does not throw any Exception as such when the Primary Key generation strategy opted is AUTO. That is where i am confused. Please help.

Comment: As I said, try setting the parenbt field of the child in your business code, before persist is called, and not in the PostPersist callback. @Mikko Maunu has it right: you can't rely on the ordering, and the primary key generation could have an effect on it. Just do what's required by the spec: initialize the owning side of the association before persisting.